# Angular is reusingn routes even after removing from routeHandlers

Tags: angular

In the code below when I call removeStore, it is actually destroying the component from DOM . But when I navigate back to same route, it's still using the same routereuse strategy. I am not sure what is wrong with my code or what am I missing.

```
import { ComponentRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy, } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  routesToCache: string[] = ["/dashboard", "/teams", "/projects"];
  storedRouteHandles: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};
  canDetach: boolean = false;

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canDetach && this.routesToCache.indexOf(this.getFullPath(route)) > -1;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    if (this.canDetach && handle && this.routesToCache.indexOf(this.getFullPath(route)) > -1) {
      this.storedRouteHandles[this.getFullPath(route)] = handle;
    }

  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const path = this.getFullPath(route);
    return (
      path && this.routesToCache.includes(path) && !!this.storedRouteHandles[path]
    );
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    if (this.routesToCache.indexOf(this.getFullPath(route)) > -1) {
      return this.storedRouteHandles[this.getFullPath(route)]
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    this.canDetach = true;
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }

  removeStore(key: string) {
    let storeUrls = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.storedRouteHandles);
    storeUrls.forEach(url=>{
      if(url.includes(key) || key.includes(url)){
        this.destroyStore(this.storedRouteHandles[url]);
        delete this.storedRouteHandles[url];
      }
    })
    

  }
  destroyStore(handle: DetachedRouteHandle) {
    const componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = handle && handle['componentRef'] ? handle['componentRef'] : null;
    console.log(componentRef)
    if (componentRef && componentRef.instance) {
      if (typeof componentRef.instance.ngOnDestroy !== 'undefined' && typeof componentRef.instance.ngOnDestroy === 'function') {
        componentRef.instance.ngOnDestroy();
      }
    }
  }
  private getFullPath(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {

    return route.pathFromRoot
      .filter(v => v.routeConfig)
      .map(v => v.routeConfig!.path)
      .join('/');
  }
}
```

I have tried using  ComponentRef.instances.Destroy() but it is throwing
Cannot insert a destroyed View in a ViewContainer!
Error: Cannot insert a destroyed View in a ViewContainer!